# Guide for touchline instructions / shouts

Tags: football-manager-2012

Is there any guide for touchline instructions / shouts for Football Manager 2012? Also, I wonder if there is any website that I can find useful shouts tactics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a blog post on [mypassion4footballmanager.com](http://www.mypassion4footballmanager.com/2012/11/football-manager-2013-tactics-shouts.html) for Football Manager 2013. I guess these touchline instructions and setup of shouts are pretty much the same as the ones for FM 2012.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah they are the same as FM2012.

We have also a guide for opposition instructions for FM12 / FM13

http://www.mypassion4footballmanager.com/2013/01/football-manager-2013-tactics-guide-to-opposition-instructions.html

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included the important information directly, rather than just a link to your site.